# Installing apptrace in OS X for debugging GAE app memory, error: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: apptrace==0.2.3

Tags: python, google-app-engine, guppy

I am trying to install and use apptrace on OS X in order to debug GAE memory...
It's been complicated and I still haven't managed to get it installed.

The [docs](https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/wiki/UsingApptrace#Tracking_Memory_Usage_in_Google_App_Engine_Python_Applications_W) say this is the easiest way to install:

easy_install apptrace

But in order for that to work I had to install a bunch of dependencies like ActiveState, Guppy and probably some more...

Lots of trials and errors later, I think I got fairly far, but still not there. So I do this in order to try to reinstall apptrace and then install it to catch all errors in the process:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall apptrace
Uninstalling apptrace:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/apptracectl
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apptrace-0.2.3-py2.7.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled apptrace
```

Then install

```
$ sudo easy_install apptrace
Searching for apptrace
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/apptrace/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/apptrace
Best match: apptrace 0.2.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/apptrace/apptrace-0.2.3.tar.gz#md5=ed03efe7afd70584a4bd461f429bdb75
Processing apptrace-0.2.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-xi0K_4/apptrace-0.2.3/setup.cfg
Running apptrace-0.2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xi0K_4/apptrace-0.2.3/egg-dist-tmp-zhij3l
Adding apptrace 0.2.3 to easy-install.pth file
Installing apptracectl script to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apptrace-0.2.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for apptrace
Finished processing dependencies for apptrace
```

It doesn't look like any errors occurred right?

Then the docs suggest to create a appengine_config.py file in the app root containing this:

```
  def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    from apptrace.middleware import apptrace_middleware
    return apptrace_middleware(app)
```

Having done that the next required step is:

```
apptracectl init <application root directory>
```

And this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/apptracectl", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: apptrace==0.2.3
```

So the error here is `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: apptrace==0.2.3`
What do I do?